# Bloodlust questions

Tags: zombicide-black-plague

Two questions about Bloodlust on Black Plague:

- Can I use it multiple times on the same turn, if I have enough actions?
- Can I use it to exit a zone with zombies? In the rulebook nothing indicates that the zone I'm originally in must be clear of zombies.

So, if I get this correctly, and these are true, I can use this ability to quickly navigate through the map, 2 zones per move (as long as there is at least one zombie per destination zone), ignoring zombies (even if I need to discard the free attack action)?

That seems pretty powerful for early game, did I get something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The wording of Bloodlust is: "Spend one Action with the Survivor: He Moves up to two Zones to a Zone containing at least one Zombie. He then gains one free Melee Action, to use immediately"

Starting with your second question, you cannot use it to exit a room with zombies. You move 0, 1, or 2 zones until you hit a zone that contains a zombie. You then immediately gain a melee action to use in that zone. If you're in a zone with a zombie, or you move into a zone containing a zombie, you stop and apply the melee action.

The answer to your first question is yes, as long as you have actions to spend, you can trigger bloodlust multiple times. However you couldn't use this to leave a zone until all of the zombies in that zone are gone.